# How do I run a command from one Docker container in another?

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, oracle12c

I've got an application and a database container. I bring them up with Docker Compose. The app container needs to wait until the db container is up and then execute a schema initialization SQL. I need to do it after my `wait-for-db` script is executed thus it should be executed in the `CMD` of the app container. The problem is that the db container doesn't contain ssh. How do I run a specific command like

```
sqlplus system/oracle @schema.sql
```

from the app container against the db container?

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE:** maybe, there is a way to execute SQL via HTTP in Oracle 12c?

Answer (score 1):

Your DB container shouldn't need ssh. Your wait-for-it script on the app container can test for availability of the oracle listener port 1521 on the db container before proceeding.

E.g.  in your docker-compose entry for the app container, assuming that "db" is the name of the db container:

```
command: "./wait-for-it.sh db:1521 runsql.sh"
```

where runsql.sh is a script that obtains the necessary oracle environment vars and runs sqlplus.

Comment: but I also need to run a Java server after the check and afaik it is better to keep this logic in the app image's Dockerfile. is there a way to execute two commands: the command in the Docker Compose yaml and then the one in the image's Dockerfile?

Comment: You cant run both, but the script that runs after wait-for-it can contain anything. It can run the schema initialization and then start the java server, and anything else you need.